# How to encrypt text using AES/Cryptography with Scribe Online API and PHP

Tags: php, cryptography, aes, tibco

I'm working with the Scribe Online API: https://dev.scribesoft.com/en/main/special_props/connection_properties.htm

They have very clear instructions on it's encryption requirements for sending data when creating a new connection which I have posted below for convenience. I'm using PHP and struggling to get their API to accept my encryption. My efforts so far (in PHP):

```
$props = [
    'Url' => 'www.web.com',
    'UserId' => 'abc123@hotmail.co.uk',
    'Password' => 'abc123',
    'SecurityToken' => '123',
    'UseBulkApiRS' => 'false',
    'UseBulkApiSYS' => 'false',
    'RefreshMetaDataUponReconnect' => 'false',
   'IncludeDeletedItemsSYS' => 'false',
];

$connector_props['connectorId'] = '8ADD76FC-525F-4B4B-B79E-945A6A762792';
$connector_props['connectorType'] = 'Salesforce';
$connector_props['color'] = '#FF00B050'; //Still Required but deprecated for Scribe Online.
$connector_props['name'] = 'Salesforce_TEST';
$connector_props['alias'] = 'Salesforce_TEST';

foreach($props as $prop_name => $val) {

    //$iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16);
    $iv = random_bytes(16);
    $pbkdf2 = hash_pbkdf2('sha1', 'ORG_KEY', 'TIBCO_SALT_PUBLIC_KEY', 1000);
    $aes = openssl_encrypt($val, 'AES-256-CBC', $pbkdf2, $options=0, $iv);
    $base64_iv = base64_encode($iv);
    $base64_val = base64_encode($aes);

    $connector_props['properties'][] = [
       'key' => $prop_name,
       'value' => $base64_iv.$base64_val,
    ];
 }
echo json_encode($connector_props, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

While I'm testing, I then copy and paste the result into their Swagger API explorer page and run a test but get back an error **"A cryptographic error has been encountered. Please verify your cryptographic key and ensure you are following the published guidelines for this API."** https://api.scribesoft.com/swagger/iframe#!/Connections/Connections_CreateConnection

The API call is expected in JSON along with some other parameters which don't need to be encrypted - so I send something like this where XXX is the encrypted value from above:

```
{
    "name": "Salesforce 4.0",
    "alias": "Salesforce 4",
    "color": "#FF00B050",
    "connectorId": "8add76fc-525f-4b4b-b79e-945a6a762792",
    "connectorType": "Salesforce",
    "properties": [
      {
        "key": "Url",
        "value": "XXX"
      },
      {
        "key": "UserId",
        "value": "XXX"
      },
      {
        "key": "Password",
        "value": "XXX"
      },
      {
        "key": "SecurityToken",
        "value": "XXX"
      },
      {
        "key": "UseBulkApiRS",
        "value": "XXX"
      },
      {
        "key": "UseBulkApiSYS",
        "value": "XXX"
      },
      {
        "key": "RefreshMetaDataUponReconnect",
        "value": "XXX"
      },
      {
        "key": "IncludeDeletedItemsSYS",
        "value": "XXX"
      },
    ],
  }
```

They do have a Javascript example: https://gitlab.com/ScribeSoftware/webapi-full-reference-app/blob/master/app/Encryption.js, but I don't really understand how to fully to convert this into PHP and get the same results that the API accepts.

Does anybody know where I am going wrong please?

### FROM THE API DOCS - POST And PUT Operations

When you POST or PUT data, the encrypted value must be base 64-encoded and appended to the base 64-encoded random initialization vector.

To encrypt a Connection property value:

1) Convert the plain text Connection value to UTF-8 encoding.

2) Generate a random array of 16 bytes. This is the Initialization Vector (IV) for the AES symmetric-key algorithm.

3)Generate a 1000 iteration-derived key from the API Access Token key and TIBCO Scribe® API salt value using the Password-Based Key Derivation Function 2 (PBKDF2) standard with Hash-based Message Authentication Code calculated with Standard Encryption Algorithm 1 (HMAC-SHA1).

4) Encrypt the UTF-8-encoded Connection property value with the AES algorithm using a key size of 256, a block size of 128, and PKCS7 padding.

5) Convert both the IV value and the encrypted Connection property value to Base 64-encoded text strings.

6) Append the Base 64-encrypted text string to the Base 64 IV text string.

Comment: `RefeshMetaDataUponReconnect` is there a typo?

Comment: Thanks - there was, but I'm not actually sending the result of this directly to Scribe as there are other parameters that make up the call so only copy+pasting the "encrypted_val" result for each $prop into the API explorer.

Comment: @kuh-chan - have updated to include the JSON call from API Explorer.

Comment: I do think that you are missing the fact that beside everything that the documentation says, you also have to select an encryption mode. You not really selected one by using `AES256` (this is an alias, and I don't know for what exactly - better not to use this string in your code but making it explicit), but the one to blame here is the documentation of this API. The correct mode (I got this from looking at the Python code example) is "CBC". I'd suggest you use `AES-256-CBC` and see if this improves the situation.

Comment: Thanks @Sven, I've updated to AES-256-CBC but this still doesn't seem to work. I get the same error back from the API.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I've finally cracked this little headache. There were a few things going on.

@Sven - your suggestion of changing the encryption alias to be explicit helped e.g. AES-256-CBC instead of AES256.

Secondly - there were a couple of extra parameters to set in the PHP functions to get this working.

I added OPENSSL_RAW_DATA to the openssl_encrypt function i.e

`$aes = openssl_encrypt($val, 'AES-256-CBC', $pbkdf2, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);`

I also had to set the key length to 256 and the raw_output to TRUE (default is false) on the hash_pbkdf2 function i.e.

```
$pbkdf2 = hash_pbkdf2('sha1', 'ORG_KEY', 'TIBCO_SALT_PUBLIC_KEY', 1000, 256, true);
```

Comment: That's very good to know. Crypto usually acts up if only one bit is wrong, and it's unfriendly against debugging attempts, I'd say.

Comment: The length parameter to hash_pbkdf2 is in bytes, not bits, so the correct value for AES256 is 32. It happens to still work because the 32 byte output is a prefix of the 256 byte output, and openssl truncates the key, but you are waisting CPU by stretching the key to 2048 bits.